# uwsgi: Unable to assign key for context when following HTTPS guide

Tags: uwsgi

I followed the exact same steps stated in the [HTTPS support](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HTTPS.html) section of the uwsgi docs but I'm getting the following error message when running `uwsgi --master --https 0.0.0.0:8443,test.crt,test.key`:

`[uwsgi-ssl] unable to assign key test.key for context "http-0.0.0.0:8443"`

Am I missing something? Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error, you have to provide the fullpath for your certificates, for example as indicated on this [discussion](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/using-private-key-for-a-standalone-uwsgi-instance/111420)  the full path for *let's encrypt* will be :

```
uwsgi --master --https 0.0.0.0:8443,/etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/fullchain.pem,/etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/privkey.pem
```